# Graph partitioning with constraints

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

Given a graph G(V,E) and a set of pairs P = {[Vi,Vj]...} I'm looking for an algorithm that will partition the graph (into the smallest possible number of path-connected patches) such that any two vertices that make up a pair in P belong to different partitions.

Any help or correct-direction-pointing would be much appreciated!

Comment: Related to the NP-hard problem multiway cut.

Comment: Thanks David! Found exactly what I was looking for with the keywords you suggested: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~toni/Courses/PCP/handouts/ugc-sparsestcut.pdf